# Setting constraints in a UITableView cell, keeping UIButtons appropriately spaced

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

this is something I have a problem with. I have done a bunch of tutorials on constraints in the interface builder and I understand pinning. My app below uses a UITableView and in the UITableView cells there are 4 UIButtons and 4 UILabels. I want to keep the spacing even like below for larger screen sizes. I guess what I mean is I want the spacing to dynamically increase with the screen size but the size of the images remains the same. If I try pinning the left and right UIButtons to their respective edges of the container this distance will not dynamically increase and there will be a big gap in the centre. How can I set it up so the layout is the same that for the smaller screen size?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some transparent views to the superview, and use them as spacers. I thought this was weird at first, but I noticed that Apple recommends it (it even turns up as a suggestion in one of their amazingly informative NSLayout debug messages)

```
[self.view addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:
                           @"H:|[spacer1][view1]\
                           [spacer2(==spacer1)][view2]\
                           [spacer3(==spacer1)][view3]\
                           [spacer4(==spacer1)][view4]\
                           [spacer5(==spacer1)]|"

                                         options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop
                                         metrics:0
                                           views:viewsDictionary]];
```

The trick, as you see, is to set each spacer's width as equal to the first spacer. Then you will get even distribution of your visible views. In you case, you would add each of your button/image combos to a container view (view1 ... view4).

In the storyboard...

[image]

The blue views represent the (transparent) spacer views. This is the setting to get them to resizeable equal widths. You should also set the visible button/imageview combos to fixed widths.

Although this example says 'add two constraints' it actually adds four, all marked as 'equal width to view' - but it seems to do the right thing. You will also want to set the space between each view ('spacing to nearest neighbour') to zero.

Comment: Wow, that does seem like a fairly exotic workaround. Can I make the transparent UIViews in the interface builder and set it up that way? If not in the interface builder I would put this code in my custom cell init method right?

Comment: @Kex, I prefer to do this kind of thing in code, so you can read your intent more easily, but it can be set in the storyboard. See my update.

Comment: The middle spacer has to be horizontally centred in the view right? The other constraints then work off the central one. I got it working thanks. Is it possible though to make the size of the spacers increase as the screen size increases? So what I have right now it basically the iPhone5 view centred in the 6. Was wondering if it was possible to implement it so the spacers enlarge and spread the buttons out a little more.

Comment: @Kex - not quite correct - the lefthand-most view's left edge is pinned to it's superview, and the right edge of the righthand-most view likewise. Each intervening view's left and right edges is pinned to it's respective left and right neighbours' right and left edges ("spacing to nearest neighbour" = 0). Then the spacers should elastically and symmetrically expand and contract to fill the  available space, as you haven't given them fixed widths.

Comment: working beautifully now, thanks. All lines in the constraint builder are blue :)

Comment: is there any easy way to get the labels below it to centre horizontally using the same centre of the image above or should I just do it programmatically?

Comment: @kex, the easy way is to put the label-buton pairs into their own containing views. The containing view gets aligned with the spacers (as I say in the answer)

Comment: I guess I can just make the width of the labels to exactly the same as the buttons above and make the spacers longer and align it the same.